# Arithmetical calculation with RStudio

Tags: r

Here is my very simple question:
How to calculate sum, difference and product between values of vector_a and vector_b, with RStudio.

```
vector_a <- (-5:5)
```

and

```
vector_b <- (0:10)
```

I have to calculate the difference/sum/product between values in vector_a and values in vector_b.

```
Sum <- sum(vector_a, vector_b)
```

returns value 55.
But product and difference functions return strange results.

If I use the command:

```
Difference <- vector_a - vector_b
```

this returns values 1, 1, 1, 1,1,..

When I use the command:

```
Difference <- diff(vector_a, vector_b)
```

it returns an error!
Can anybody explain what are the right commands for these basic calculations?

Comment: Have you actually looked at what's in vector_a and vector_b?

Comment: I ask because your results don't make sense for your output for vector_a - vector_b.  The other stuff makes sense but it should give -5 and not 1 when you look at vector_a-vector_b

Answer (score 0):

what are you looking for?

```
> vector_a <- (-5:5)
> vector_b <- (0:10)
> vector_a - vector_b
 [1] -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5 -5
> vector_a + vector_b
 [1] -5 -3 -1  1  3  5  7  9 11 13 15
> vector_a * vector_b
 [1]  0 -4 -6 -6 -4  0  6 14 24 36 50
> prod(vector_a,vector_b)
[1] 0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Sorry for the late answer. Your calculations are right.